# Install VueJS components in a rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5, vue-strap

I'm trying to get a set of VueJS components i.e. VueStrap, installed in a Rails project. VueJS is setup and working correctly.

Typically I would use npm to install VueStrap if I was doing this outside of a Rails project.

How can I install VueStrap in a rails project?

Comment: You should still be able to use npm, though I think yarn is preferred with rails, just try running `yarn add vue-strap` from your project root. (add -D flag to save to dev-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks! I ran that, how can test it to see if it works? I have a simple hello world vue template which is working fine. How can I include vue-strap  into the project and show a button for example?

Comment: Hope you this will help you vuejs installation doubts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574225/steps-to-install-vuejs-via-webpack-in-rails-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) gem.
You can then use webpack + yarn very easily with Rails.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go by any of these routes mentioned above, you can always set up the **frontend** as a separate entity.

You can set up CORS using `rack-cors` gem, and use it to communicate with VueJS frontend.

That way Rails doesn't have to be concerned about the specific webpack/yarn/gulp, or whatever setup you have for your frontend logic.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you this will help you vuejs with  webpacker gem installation doubts

[**Steps to install Vuejs via webpack in rails app**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574225/steps-to-install-vuejs-via-webpack-in-rails-app)